# Transport layer - who makes the demultiplexing phase?

Tags: networking, socket

I'm reading the `computer network a top down approach 6th edition`, and I'm at the transport layer. I understand how a packet from a client is sent to the server through the client socket, but when the server receive the packet, who read the packet information and pass it on to the correct process?

As for TCP, at first a connection is established between 2 processes. Same question here, who or what is doing the multiplexing and pass the packet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each client/server IP connection is identified by a tuple composed by five elements:

- ip protocol
- source address
- source port
- destination address
- destination port

When a connection is established, both the client and server IP stacks remember the respective tuple in a specific in-memory table. Later, when a packet arrive, it search the connection table to find the correct tuple and to see what specific process is listening for it.

As a practical example, consider issuing the command `netstat -n -t -p` on a linux box. On my PC, it shows the following output:

```
[root@centos-webdev ~]# netstat -n -t -p
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 172.31.255.240:45414        1.1.8.246:25                TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0     64 172.31.255.240:22           1.1.9.6:2205                ESTABLISHED 10604/sshd
```

Give a look a the last line: if shows that there is an established SSH connection from remote address 1.1.9.6, port 2205 to the local IP 172.31.255.240, port 22. The rightmost field explain that the ssh executable, with PID 10604, is listening for packet belonging to that specific connection.